# Output is directed to /dev/tty instead of standard "stdin"

Tags: bash, subprocess, stdio, tty, os.system

Currently I am working on executing/parsing bash commands in a Python script. I am using specific software that utilizes bash commands, so I am importing the OS and subprocess modules to do so in Python. In the past when I ran:

`>os.system('insert specific (bash) software command')`

-- the output was sent to my standard controlling terminal (A.K.A "dev/tty" in case that wasn't the most accurate wording) for this process and there didn't seem to be any problems. However, when I run another one of the software's commands, the following in my terminal is displayed:

[image: error message]

I have flipped through the software's guidebook and a few threads on Stack, yet I cannot seem to identify the source of this problem. Is this a common issue when using these modules, or is it perhaps more intrinsic to the software itself?

Comment: If an example of the script that I am running would be of help, please let me know!

Comment: Show the error message in code block, not in screenshot. Also, it would be hard to tell the problem without knowing the command you issued. Did you search the error message online like [here](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/lheasoft/scripting.html)?

Comment: @dibery Thank you for your input! I actually visited that website initially, prior to posting on Stack, and I thought that the solution would be found by running the export commands under "Bourne shell (sh/bash)" -- and then proceeding with my code. However the same error message was returned.

Comment: `os.system` doesn't change where stdout is directed. It goes to the same place your Python program's stdout is going, which depends on how that program was started.

Comment: Anyhow, this looks more like a situation where your process simply doesn't have a controlling TTY assigned in the first place, and that has nothing to do with the Python program or its use of `os.system`, and _everything_ to do with in what context that program was started.